# Keep mysql.socks

Tags: mysql, datadir

I moved mysql `datadir` to `/storage-s01/mysql`, but `socket` is still located at the same directory `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.
Do I have to keep `socket` at the same directory as `datadir`?

BTW, If I want to change `datadir`, i have to change that only `/etc/my.cnf` file?

I have mariadb

Answer (score 0):

`my.cnf` should suffice for moving `datadir`.  You will need a restart.

If `my.cnf` mentions `mysql.sock`, then be sure to change that, too.  If it does not, then it will be assumed to be in your new `datadir`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change Data directory dynamically. Only option is you have to change in configuration file and bounce the database.